# Selecting certain values from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I used

```
numpy.genfromtxt('...', dtype=None, usecols=
(0,6,7,8,9,19,24,29,31,33,34,37,39,40,41,42,43,44), names=
['sn','off1','dir1','off2','dir2','type','gal','dist','htype','d1','d2','pa','ai','b','berr
','b0','k','kerr']))
```

to read some data.

The array `type` includes a bunch of different strings, such as Ia, II, etc.

How do I create a variable that only uses certain strings of `type`

I, for instance, would like to set `TypeIa =` to all the strings of the array `type` that are 'Ia', 'Iabg', and 'Iat'.

Comment: what exactly you want? what is `type`, `la`, `lat`, those tokens are not mentioned in your code excerpt

Comment: I edited my post.  Hopefully that makes it a little clearer.  `type` is just one of the columns from my data file.  `Ia` and `Iat` are strings that are in the `type` array.  The `type` array contains different strings, but I only want to use the ones that are `Ia`, `Iabg`, and `Iat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function. Also, for simplicity in the following sample I use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). You might also find it handy.

First, I prepared some test data, do not expose code here for simplicity

```
>>> type(data)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> data['type']
['0-19' '1-19' '2-19' '3-19' '4-19' '5-19' '6-19' '7-19' '8-19' '9-19']
```

Then, let's define filtering function

```
from functools import partial
def startswith(string, prefix):
    return str.startswith(string, prefix)

startswith8 = partial(startswith, prefix='8-')
```

Finally, we are ready to apply out filtering function:

```
>>> filter(startswith8, data['type'])
['8-19']
```